# How to install mysql server and xampp server both in same operating system

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In my machine there has Xampp server. Recently I install MySQL server edition on that machine. It occurs an error. Then change port and socket in config.inc.php page. Again it shows an error. to solve uninstall both Xampp server and MySQL. Again try to run both Xampp and MySQL both. First install Xampp then install mySQL work bench. Now it shows an errors [ #1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_recent' and (SELECT `tables`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_recent` WHERE `username` = 'root' )]. 
Please help me to solve this problem. and tell me the procedure without conflict database,how to install both xampp server and mysql server.

Comment: You can check this: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install xampp in port 3306 and mySql in port 3307.

Comment: I have this problem currently with my XAMPP installation. It is clashing with my standard MySQL installation which I don't want to remove. I have changed port on related files such as my.ini, php.ini and properties.ini to no avail. I'm still with no luck. Is there any other way to make XAMPP work alongside existing MySQL installation without conflicting?

Comment: you can install MySQL on different directory and different service name.